# How to change default language link?

Tags: php, laravel

I don't want by default, our application’s open to `http://localhost:8000/fa/`

I want by default, our application’s change to `http://localhost:8000`

how can change to `http://localhost:8000`

app.php

```
'locale' => 'fa',
'locales' => ['fa' => 'Farsi' , 'pa' => 'Pashtu'],

'fallback_locale' => 'fa',
```

my language middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $locale = $request->segment(1);
    if(! array_key_exists($locale , config('app.locales'))) {
        $segments = $request->segments();
        $segments[0] = config('app.fallback_locale');
        return redirect(implode('/', $segments));
    }
    app()->setLocale($locale);
    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting you can just set the locale:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
        $locale = $request->segment(1);
        if(! array_key_exists($locale , config('app.locales'))) {
            $locale = config('app.fallback_locale');
        }
        app()->setLocale($locale);
        return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a multilingual site, and french is the default locale, i suggest using this [Package](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization), and they have the option to hide the default locale.